# How to get (keyup.enter) event on option of datalist in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, html, typescript

How to get (keyup.enter) event on option of datalist in Angular 6

**My HTML Code:**

```
<input list="filteredArray" (keyup)="filterRecord(empForm.controls['empname'].value)" type="text" formControlName="empname" />
  <datalist id="filteredArray">
     <option (keyup.enter)="SelectRecord()" *ngFor="let item of filteredArray">{{item}}</option>
  </datalist>
```

**My Typescript Code:**

```
filtervendor(name: any) {
   this.filteredArray = ['AB','SD','DF','FG'];
}

SelectRecord() {
    console.log('select');
  }
```

Above solution is working for enter button.

In above example I am filtering employees on keyup and show it in datalist, If I select one employee or tab out on employee its name is populating in textbox but I want to get (keyup.enter) event or tab out event for option in datalist and filteredArray gets empty.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML Code**

```
<input list="filteredArray" (keyup)="filterRecord(empForm.controls['empname'].value, $event)" type="text" formControlName="empname" />
              <datalist id="filteredArray">
                <option (keyup.enter)="SelectRecord()" *ngFor="let item of filteredArray">{{item}}</option>
              </datalist>
```

**Type Script Code**

```
   private filterRecord(value, event)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 13)
            {
               // enter keycode
            }        
            else if (event.keyCode == 9)
            {
               // tab keycode
            } 
        }
```

check for more keycodes [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: I want to (keyup.enter) event for option inside datalist

Comment: @Tejas you will apply `keyup.enter` on change event of datalist

Comment: In datalist as I am printing {{item}}. Suppose I want to print {{item.name}} and that value should be {{item.id}} but id should not display, how should I do that?

Comment: @Tejas you can display value here `<option *ngFor="let item of filteredArray">{{item.name}}</option>` and give option a `value` property as `value={{item.id}}`.. then `ngModel` will be having `ID` of selected option

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to filter the `datalist` by yourself, the browser does this for you. After all it's just a collection of predefined values. You can get the "selected" with `[(ngModel)]` as with any other input.

Example:

```
<input  type="text" name="empname" list="filteredArray" [(ngModel)]="inputValue"/>
<datalist id="filteredArray">
  <option *ngFor="let item of filteredArray">{{item}}</option>
</datalist>

<p>
  The value is: {{inputValue}}
</p>
```

TS:

```
  filteredArray = ['AB', 'SD', 'DF', 'FG'];
  inputValue = "";
```

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9o9dt